# Liferay Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay-6

Has anyone experienced this error?

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAutoProxyCreator#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/springframework/core/LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor

Im using Liferay 6.2 with Spring 4

Comment: LIferay is using an older incompatible version of Spring which takes precedence over your version... Hence incompatible classes from different versions are loaded.

Comment: i tried updating the jars but it still didnt work. is there any work around for this problem?

Comment: Make sure you aren't mixing versions of spring jars (locally and from liferay) and make sure you are using versions that are supported for the JDK you are using (older versions have also problems with JDK 1.8 due to the ASM version used). You also might run into issues with Liferay when using newer versions as they might not be (binary) compatible with the older versions (or even worse classes might have been removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend mixing up other versions of Spring with Liferay than the one supported itself. You can check version of given external plugin by looking it this xml file

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/lib/versions.xml

When you grep this page for '**Spring**' occurs, you see **3.0.7** version, which is right one to use with 6.2.X Liferay.